# Can you please explain how this truncateStr function works?

Tags: dapps, addresses, frontend

I understand that it makes the address on the frontend appear shorter as you specify the string to let it know how much shorter. What I do not understand is the math behind it and what substring keyword means? Can anyone help me out here please! I would really appreciate it! Thanks! Math.ceil?? Math.floor?? Why do we devide by two?? ...

```js
const truncateStr = (fullStr, strLen) => {
  if (fullStr.length <= strLen) return fullStr;
  const seperator = '...';
  let seperatorLength = seperator.length;
  const charsToShow = strLen - seperatorLength;
  const frontChars = Math.ceil(charsToShow / 2);
  const backChars = Math.floor(charsToShow / 2);
  return (
    fullStr.substring(0, frontChars) +
    seperator +
    fullStr.substring(fullStr.length - backChars)
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the line `if (fullStr.length <= strLen) return fullStr;` will simply return if the `fullStr` is already shorter than the truncating length that we wanted it to be, it simply returns because there's nothing else to do, it's already "truncated".

It uses a separator `...`. So, if I have a string like this: `ThisIsMyString`, and I want to truncate it to 5 characters, counting the separator `...`, it would result in `T...g`, 5 characters counting the 3 dots.

The line `const charsToShow = strLen - seperatorLength;` extracts the separator length (which is 3, due to 3 dots `...`) from the `strLen` because the function will show `strLen` characters as the truncated string, but counting it's own `...` in between.

The following lines:

```js
const frontChars = Math.ceil(charsToShow / 2);
const backChars = Math.floor(charsToShow / 2);
```

`Math.ceil` is used to round up a number. If `charsToShow` is 3 and `charsToShow / 2` = 1.5, then `Math.ceil` will make it 2, because it will round up 1.5 to 2.

`Math.floor` is used to round down a number. If `charsToShow` is 3 and `charsToShow / 2` = 1.5, then `Math.ceil` will make it 1, because it will round down 1.5 to 1.

The reason why it is using `Math.ceil` for `frontChars` to get the range of the first characters is to make sure that at least the result of the division will be 1. For example, `1 / 2` is 0.5, using 0.5 in something like `"etc".subsctring(0, 0.5)"` would return `""`, an empty string. And you don't want that. That's why you want to make sure that even if the result of the division is 0.5 or something like that, it is round it to 1, to at least have 1 character: `"etc".subsctring(0, 1)"` returns `"e"`.

The reason why it uses `Math.floor` the get the range of the last characters for `backChars` is because you don't want an extra character at the end, which would be an empty string in Javascript. For example, `"etc".substring(2.5)` returns `"c"`. `"etc".substring(2)` also returns `"c"`. But `"etc".substring(3)` returns `""`; Which means that you really don't want to round up in this case to get the last characters of the string.

The Javascript string method `substring` receives 2 optional parameters and returns you a range of the string. If you don't pass any parameters, it returns the original string: `"etc".substring()` returns `"etc"`. If you pass only one parameter, it will make a copy of the string from that index until the end: `"etc".substring(1)` returns `"tc"`, because the character at index `is`"t"`, and it then returns all the characters from` "t"`all the way to the end of the string. When you pass 2 parameters, it returns a copy of the string within the range provider, being the last parameter exclusive.`"etc".substring(1,2)`returns`"t"`, because the second parameter 2 is exclusive, meaning that it will copy only one character starting from the character at index 1.

To clarify, in this case `"ThisIsMyString".substring(1,4)`, it will return `"his"`, because the character at index 1 is `"h"`, and it will copy 3 characters because of the range 1-4 exclusive, (4 - 1 = 3 characters to copy).

`"ThisIsMyString".substring(1)` would return `"hisIsMyString"`, because when you only pass one parameter, js assumes that the second parameter is the length of the string, so it will copy everything from index 1 to the end. Which is ideal in this case to copy all the last characters that it needs.

And the reason why it is dividing `charsToShow` by 2, is because it is breaking the string in 2, to then insert the separator in between.

I hope it helped.

Comment: It really helped! Thank you so much!!!!